# Backup VSS Issues

Tags: backup, vss, ntbackup

I've got this server, and we've been having VSS issues for quite awhile.  We've tried every form of re-registering the VSS drivers we can think of.

- NTbackup won't run a system state backup
- vssadmin list writers doesn't list anything.
- We're getting VSS error 12302 in the event log.

Has anyone ran into a situation like this before?  We're thinking the next step, if possible, is a complete reinstall of the VSS.

Edit:

**General Info**

Role: Domain Controller

OS: Windows Small Business Server 2003

Version: Small Business Server Service Pack 2 Build 3790

**Software**

MS SQL Server 2005

Microsoft Exchange Server 2003 SP1

Comment: What other software is running on the server? I had similar issues on a server with Truecrypt encrypting a portable HDD attached to it. Carbonite has also caused problems for me.

Comment: Use the steps outlined in the next Microsoft article. https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/940184/error-message-when-you-run-the-vssadmin-list-writers-command-on-a-wind Remember to backup you registry before performing any changes to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940032

Comment: We've done this, and still hasn't worked.